# I can,t figure out how to split the string correctly

Tags: python

I'm trying to make only the first letter of the song titles show but the artist show in full, for example - Michael Jackson B      J    - for billie jean, this is my code followed by the output.

```
myfile = open("songs.txt", "r")
import random 
with open("songs.txt") as select: 
    song=(random.choice(select.readlines())) 


artist,song_title = song.split(" ",1)

for x in song_title:
    letter1=x[0:1] 
    print(artist,letter1)
```

OUTPUT:

```
Eminem C
Eminem L
Eminem E
Eminem A
Eminem N
Eminem I
Eminem N
Eminem G
Eminem  
Eminem O
Eminem U
Eminem T
Eminem  
Eminem M
Eminem Y
Eminem  
Eminem C
Eminem L
Eminem O
Eminem S
Eminem E
Eminem T
Eminem
```

This is the whole challenge

TASK 1
Noel is creating a music quiz game.
The game stores a list of song names and their artist (e.g. the band or solo artist name). The player needs to try and guess the song name.
The game is played as follows:
• A random song name and artist are chosen.
• The artist and the ﬁrst letter of each word in the song title are displayed.
• The user has two chances to guess the name of the song.
• If the user guesses the answer correctly the ﬁrst time, they score 3 points. If the user guesses the answer correctly the second time they score 1 point. The game repeats.
• The game ends when a player guesses the song name incorrectly the second time. Only authorised players are allowed to play the game.
Where appropriate, input from the user should be validated.
Design, develop, test and evaluate a system that:

1. Allows a player to enter their details, which are then authenticated to ensure that they are an authorised player.
2. Stores a list of song names and artists in an external file.
3. Selects a song from the file, displaying the artist and the first letter of each word of the song title.
4. Allows the user up to two chances to guess the name of the song, stopping the game if they guess a song incorrectly on the second chance.
5. If the guess is correct, add the points to the player’s score depending on the number of guesses.
6. Displays the number of points the player has when the game ends.
7. Stores the name of the player and their score in an external file.
8. Displays the score and player name of the top 5 winning scores from the external file.

Comment: If it's a challenge, then the best learning experience ist to read good tutorials on `Python`, study some string functions and e.g. regular expressions. Sure you could as well post it here, have it answered but then the next challenge is equally difficult, isn't it?

Comment: If your file has lines comprised of both artist and song title, how do you know where the artist's name ends and the song title starts? In the case of Eminem, he's mononymous so his name is the first token after the *split()* but what about Elton John or Billy Ray Cyrus? You'll probably find a CSV file helpful for this challenge

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with the below code:

```
song_letter = ""

for item in song_title.split():
    song_letter+=item[0]+" "
```

which will iterate over each words and get the first letter appended to the variable.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of looping over `song_title`, loop over `song_title.split()` (since `split()` without arguments will split at whitespace), e.g.

```
song = "Eminem CLEANING OUT MY CLOSET"
artist, song_title = song.split(" ",1)
print(artist, end=" ")
for word in song_title.split():
    print(word[0], end=" ")

print()
```

prints out

```
Eminem C O M C
```